# C# - Can I map calls from one function to actually call another

Tags: c#, .net

Here's my situation: I have to temporarily downgrade from .NET4 to .NET3.5 for a while.  However, I want to be able to migrate back as quickly as possible later on.

There's some functions in .`NET4` that we use that have no `3.5` equivalents, such as `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`.  I can implement this function myself, but I don't want to have to update dozens of calls to use another static class (such as `MyString.IsNullOrWhitespace`).

Is there a way, perhaps by taking advantage of some creative "using" syntax to map all references to `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` to `MyString.IsNullOrWhitespace?`  Or is there any other feature or functionality of the C# compiler that can do this?  Or do I just have to globally search and replace `"String.IsNullOrWhitespace"` to `"MyString.IsNullOrWhitespace"`?  Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio or any other decent IDE, global search/replace operations are trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for extension methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

You won't have to change your code at all. you can implement your own IsNullOrWhiteSpace that attaches right onto the string class.  Provided you reference the namespace where your extension method resides.

**EDIT:**
I just realized that IsNullOrWhiteSpace is a static method, and you can't create static extension methods.  But perhaps you could do something like:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this String str)
        {
            // ToDo: implement this
        }
    }   
}
```

which would be called on actual instances of string, i.e.:

```
if(myString.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
```

which is actually slightly shorter than what you are currently doing:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString))
```

Comment: He would have to change the code. You can't have a static extension method (i.e. adding a static method to an existing type).

Comment: Yea static extension methods are a feature I would /love/ to see in C#!

Comment: Perhaps a nit, but in this case if myString is null won't that throw instead of the advertised check of IsNullOrWhiteSpace?

Comment: @Damon8er: that depends on the implementation, which is where the Todo comment is.  Obviously the first thing to do would be to return true if str is null.

Comment: Brad Wilson verifies that calling extensions on null instances are ok: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html

Comment: This is worth an upvote just because I never knew you could call an extension method on a null instance, but I guess that makes sense from a compiler point of view.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your code minimally when you upgrade from 3.5 to 4.0, you can create an extension method as Neil N suggested.  When you upgrade, you can rewrite the extension method to wrap the framework's static method, rather than changing all the call sites:

BEFORE

```
namespace ExtensionMethods 
{ 
    public static class MyExtensions 
    { 
        public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this String str) 
        { 
            // ToDo: implement this 
        } 
    }    
}
```

AFTER

```
namespace ExtensionMethods 
{ 
    public static class MyExtensions 
    { 
        public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this String str) 
        { 
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
        } 
    }    
}
```

If you use a refactoring tool such as ReSharper, you could then use the "Inline Method" refactoring, which would be safer and easier than a global search-and-replace operation.

Comment: Some people do this simply to make the the static methods act like instance methods, as it is more "fluid"